# License Check Loop?

Tags: android

Maybe the code kind of shows what I'm attempting to do, so I'll start with that

```
private void getLicenseResults() {

    if (licensed && didCheck == true) {

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(
                            "***.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    if (didCheck == false) {

        Toast.makeText(Splash.this, "Checking License, Please Wait",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    getLicenseResults();
                    Log.i("LICENSE", "re-checking");
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

I ran the license check without trying to loop it before, and it worked except if the checking took more than a couple seconds it skipped over the

```
if (licensed && didCheck == true)
```

and the activity just kind of stood and waited without launching my main activity (this check is on the splash screen).

So I want the "if didCheck = true" part to be called only after didCheck is in fact finally true.  I'm sure there's an easy solution, but I'm self-taught and I have no experience with loops or callbacks(?).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting didCheck to true in your second if statement before the call to getLicenseResults

Comment: didCheck is set true by a background process currently going on during this.  The "license checker" is a separate class, and when it finally finishes (speed varies by internet connection) it sets didCheck from false to true.